# Maintaining a Cairo drawing in Gtk.DrawingArea() after scroll event

Tags: scroll, gtk, pygtk, cairo, pygobject

I'm working on an annotation tool for some images and decided to use GTK for the task. I have a Gtk.DrawingArea() nested inside Gtk.Viewport() which is nested in Gtk.ScrolledWindow() to enable scrolling of the drawing area. The drawing area contains an image and shapes are drawn on top of the image using Cairo on each mouse click event.

If I understand correctly, scrolling by default causes a redrawing of Gtk.DrawingArea() which makes all of shapes disappear. Is there any way (other than keeping a list of coordinates and redrawing every shape on each scroll event) to maintain those shapes?

```
import gi
import math
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):

  def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title = "Test")
    self.drag = False
    self.drag_x = 0
    self.drag_y = 0
    self.pos = []
    viewport = Gtk.Viewport()
    self.darea = Gtk.DrawingArea()
    self.darea.connect("draw", self.expose)

    self.pixbuf = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file("anntool/test.jpg")
    self.darea.set_size_request(self.pixbuf.get_width(), self.pixbuf.get_height());

    self.maximize() # maximize window on load
    grid = Gtk.Grid()
    self.add(grid)

    scrolled = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scrolled.set_hexpand(True)
    scrolled.set_vexpand(True)
    scrolled.set_kinetic_scrolling(True)
    self.v_scroll = scrolled.get_vadjustment()
    self.h_scroll = scrolled.get_hadjustment()
    scrolled.add_events(Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK | Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK | Gdk.EventMask.BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK)
    scrolled.connect("button-release-event", self.release)
    scrolled.connect("button-press-event", self.click)
    scrolled.connect("motion-notify-event", self.mousemove)
    # scrolled.connect("scroll_event", self.scroll)

    viewport.add(self.darea)
    scrolled.add(viewport)

    grid.add(scrolled)

  def click(self, widget, event):
    if (event.button == 1):
      cr = self.darea.get_parent_window().cairo_create()
      x = self.h_scroll.get_value() + event.x
      y = self.v_scroll.get_value() + event.y
      cr.arc(x, y, 10, 0, 2 * math.pi)
      cr.set_source_rgba(0.0, 0.6, 0.0, 1)
      cr.fill()
    if (event.button == 2):
      self.drag =  True
      self.drag_x = event.x
      self.drag_y = event.y
      self.pos = [self.h_scroll.get_value(), self.v_scroll.get_value()]

  def release(self, widget, event):
    self.drag =  False
    default = Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.ARROW)
    widget.get_window().set_cursor(default)

  def mousemove(self, widget, event):
    if self.drag:
      self.h_scroll.set_value(self.pos[0] + self.drag_x - event.x)
      self.v_scroll.set_value(self.pos[1] + self.drag_y - event.y)
      hand = Gdk.Cursor(Gdk.CursorType.HAND1)
      widget.get_window().set_cursor(hand)

  def scroll(self, widget, event):
    print("scrolled")

  def expose(self, widget, event):
    Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(event, self.pixbuf, 0, 0)
    event.paint()

win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Doesn't an expose event mean you have to redraw everything? Which means, also the stuff that you drew outside of expose events? Also, I vaguely remember that drawing outside of the expose event is discouraged. Instead, one should use `gtk_widget_queue_draw` to cause a redraw to be scheduled.

Comment: @UliSchlachter, it's due to my lack of experience I didn't realize that expose event (or "draw" event GTK+ 3) is called on every scroll event. In the end, I decided to keep track of the list of coordinates for added points and redraw all of them on each "draw" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Uli Schlachter pointed out, redraw is executed on each scroll event, therefore one need to keep track of added points (e.g. with a list) and redraw each point in `expose()` function in the code above.